# On the equations $x^yy^z=z^x$ and $w^x+x^y+y^z=z^w$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Recently, I considered the equation
$$x^yy^z=z^x\qquad(x,y,z\in\{2,3,\ldots\}).\tag{1}$$
The equation $(1)$ has infinitely many solutions with $x=z$ including $$(x,y,z)=(n^n,n^{n-1},n^n),\ (n^{2n^2},n^{2(n^2-1)},n^{2n^2})\quad \ (n=2,3,\ldots).$$
Actually, all the positive solutions of the equation $x^yy^x=x^x$ are given by
$$x=\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{a_i\prod_{j=1}^r\ p_j^{a_j}}\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ 
y=\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{a_i(\prod_{j=1}^r \ p_j^{a_j}-1)},\tag{2}$$
where $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ are distinct primes, and $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ are nonnegative integers. This can be easily deduced by using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. What about solutions of $(1)$ with $x\not=z$? I have made the following conjecture.

**Conjecture 1.** The only solutions of $(1)$ with $x\not=z$ are as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}(x,y,z)=&(8,2,2),\, (9,3,3),\, (4,2,8),\, (16,4,32),\, \\&(128,64,32),\,(512,256,32),\, (686,392,98).\end{aligned}\tag{3}$$

Z. Zhang and P. Yuan [Int. J. Number Theory 8(2012), 813--821] conjectured that the equation $x^y+y^z=z^x$ only has one positive integer solution $(x,y,z)=(1,1,2)$. Now I state my second conjecture.

**Conjecture 2.** For the equation
$$w^x+x^y+y^z=z^w\qquad\ (w,x,y,z\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}\ \mbox{and}\ w+y>2),\tag{4}$$
the only solutions are
$$(w,x,y,z)=(2,1,1,2),\ (3,1,2,2),\ (4,3,2,3).\tag{5}$$

**QUESTION.** How to solve Conjectures 1 and 2?

Your are welcome to make comments or check Conjectures 1 and 2 further.

Comment: I have verified Conjecture 2 for $w,x,y,z\le 256$.

Comment: This is not very useful, but one can prove that $\min(y,z,w)\not =w$ and that "$x\lt z$ or $z\lt w$".